# Simple examples of A-infinity categories/algebras

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-topology, soft-question, homological-algebra, higher-category-theory

I'm looking for simple examples of non-trivial $A_\infty$-algebras/$A_\infty$-categoies which ideally can be understood in an introductory talk in a grad student seminar.

A few examples I know are Fukaya-type categories of a surface, Massey product and an $A_\infty$ algebra given by multiplication table in the book Algebraic Operads by Loday and Vallette's book.

The first two are a little involved in my opinion ($J$-holomorphic disks or Kadeishvili's theorem) and the third is kind of unintuitive to me. I'm wondering if there's some intuitive construction which can produce $A_\infty$-algebras/$A_\infty$-categoies directly.

Comment: Doesn't Loday-Vallette give the following example : take a homotopy retraction $H\to A$ with $A$ a dga, then $H$ gets an $A_\infty$-algebra structure ?

Comment: Keller's paper https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9910179# is a good reference for $A_\infty$-algebras. He mentions loop spaces as a motivating example.

Comment: To Max: I do know this example but I'm not sure if I can convince people in five minutes why this should work. I think they prove it by some induction plus direct computation. I would be happy to know if there's a intuitive way to see why this works.

Comment: To John Palmieri: Thanks. This is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Loop spaces are a good motivating example. It is important to notice however that that they are only homotopic to $A_\infty$-spaces, because of the failure of the concatenation map to be strictly unital.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few nice small examples for initial illustration in Lu-Palmieri-Wu-Zhang's paper "A-infinity algebras for ring theorists".

One of them is the $A_\infty$-Koszul dual of $k[t]/(t^n)$ for $n\geq 3$ (this computation can also be found in Dag Madsen's PhD thesis). It is given as an algebra by $k[x,y]/(x^2)$ with higher multiplication given by $m_n(xy^{t_1},\dots,xy^{t_n})=y^{1+\sum_{i=1}^n t_i}$ and all other higher multiplications vanish, i.e. $m_k=0$ for $k\neq 2,n$ and $m_n$ applied to some expression not involving $x$ is also $0$.

Another nice example one can find there explicitly is that a (non-unital) $A_\infty$-algebra on an $A_\infty$-algebra $A$ concentrated in degrees $1$ and $2$ is given by arbitrary $\Bbbk$-linear maps $m_n\colon (A^1)^{\otimes n}\to A^2$. Which is of course seems a bit artificial but gives you some impression how many possibilities you actually have.